# Erroro in creating stock move odoo 12 from other module ( action_donne and action_confirm')?

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I want to create a move after clicking on button in odoo 12 but there is no action confirm and action_done methods 
did they change their name in odoo 12.?
thanks

```
"-----------------------------------------------------------------"
'stock.move' object has no attribute 'action_confirm'
'stock.move' object has no attribute 'action_done'
"-----------------------------------------------------------------"
@api.multi
def _mvm(self, piece):
    stock_move_obj = self.env["stock.move"]
    location_id=self.env['stock.location'].search([('name' ,'=', 'PDR')], limit=1)
    location_dest_id=self.env['stock.location'].search([('id' ,'=', 7)], limit=1)
    vals = {
                'product_id': piece.product.id,
                'product_uom_qty': piece.use_qty,
                'name': piece.product.name,
                'product_uom':piece.product.uom_id.id,
                'location_id': location_id.id,
                'location_dest_id':location_dest_id.id
       }
    #pdb.set_trace()
    mv = stock_move_obj.sudo().create(vals)
    mv.action_confirm()
    mv.sudo().action_done()
    return True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MOHAMED

The Error shows that the object does not have this method at all,
with replacing the method to `mv._action_confirm` & `mv._action_done`.

Thanks